# Add a variable to a javascript callback

Tags: javascript

I am using a library where I must define a callback function, and the library will execute this function upon a certain event:

```
// initialize the callback for the library.
// `lib` is the main variable for the library and is defined globally
function initializations() {
    var extra_var = 'pass me into the callback';
    var libprops = {
        libcallback: function(settings) { do stuff }
    };
    lib.reconfigure(libprops);
}
```

The library then runs the callback like so (I have no control over this):

```
var settings = 'xyz';
libprops.libcallback(settings);
```

So clearly, one of the variables input to my defined callback will be the `settings` variable. However I also want to pass in a variable of my own:

```
function mycallback(settings, extra_var) {
    // do stuff involving settings
    // do stuff involving extra_var
}
```

How can I define `libprops.libcallback` within `initializations()` so that `extra_var` is passed in, but with function `mycallback` defined elsewhere? Ie like so:

```
function mycallback(settings, extra_var) {
    // do stuff involving settings
    // do stuff involving extra_var
}
```

Is this possible? The reason I want to define `mycallback()` outside of `initializations()` is that `mycallback()` is quite large and its messy to have it defined inside `initializations()`.

It seems like a closure would solve the issue, but I'm not quite sure how to construct it. Here is a preliminary attempt:

```
function initializations() {
    var extra_var = 'pass me into the callback';
    var libprops = {
        libcallback: (function(settings) {
            mycallback(settings, extra_var)
        })(extra_var)
    };
    lib.reconfigure(libprops);
}
```

Comment: you already have a closure, therefore you don't need to pass in `extra_var` anywhere, it's available to your anonymous callback function already, as `extra_var`

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, I realize that, but I want to define `mycallback()` outside of `initializations()`. I have updated the question to include this important requirement. Sorry to change the game. It was obvious to me, but I realized it was not originally included in the question :P

Comment: just: `libcallback: function(settings) {..}`, remove the function call with `extra_var`

Comment: your attempt will set libcallback to undefined, because your IIFE is returning undefined - however, you'll have more issues because mycallback will be called **immediately** rather than as a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have a closure, therefore you don't need to pass in `extra_var` anywhere, it's available to your anonymous callback function already, as `extra_var`

```
function initializations() {
    var extra_var = 'pass me into the callback';
    var libprops = {
        libcallback: function(settings) {
            // do stuff 
            // you can do stuff with extra_var here too
        }
    };
    lib.reconfigure(libprops);
}
```

> as per extra information in comment, just call your `myfunction` in the anonymous callback, passing in extra_vars as the second parameter (or first if you want, doesn't matter, it's your function)

```
function initializations() {
    var extra_var = 'pass me into the callback';
    var libprops = {
        libcallback: function(settings) {
            mycallback(settings, extra_var);
        }
    };
    lib.reconfigure(libprops);
}
```

there's probably another way using `.bind` - however, no need for such gymnastics in such a simple scenario

Comment: Looks promising! I will test and accept if it works. Many thanks!

Comment: how can i access `lib` from within `mycallback()`? If its an anonymous function inline with the object then its just `this`, but `this` does not refer to `lib` within `mycallback()`

Comment: ah I found i can pass `this` to `mycallback()` as a third parameter from the anonymous function during the definition like so: `libcallback: function(settings) { mycallback(settings, extra_var, this);}`

Comment: `how can i access lib from within mycallback()` -  I know you found an answer, but I didn't think there was an issue with accessing `lib` as it was not treated in any way special in the question - I automatically assumed it'd just be "in scope" at that point (within `initializations` functions as it is in your code)

Comment: I know I did originally said `lib` was defined globally. This was true at the time I wrote the question, but I have since changed that requirement. No worries about not addressing that - I didn't expect you to read my mind haha

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a closure will do, but you don't need to call the function "now".
You can create a function that references your local `extra_var` and pass it around:

```
function initializations() {
    var extra_var = 'pass me into the callback';
    var libprops = {
        libcallback: function(settings) {
            // you can access both settings passed in as a parameter
            // and extra_var, referenced locally.
            var settingsLocal = settings,
              another = extra_var;
        }
    };
    lib.reconfigure(libprops);
}
```

If `extra_var` has a fixed value like in the example, you're done. Elsewhere, you need to elaborate on your request.